# Force kotlin coroutines code, to not be synchronized by Javas @Synchronized

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to write a code, that will let me test situations, in which Javas `@Synchronized` is not enough, to synchronize Kotlin coroutines. From my understanding, the code below:

```
var sharedCounter: Long = 0

@Synchronized
suspend fun updateCounter() {
    delay(2)
    sharedCounter++
    delay(2)
    yield()
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    var regularCounter: Long = 0
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + Job())
    val jobs = mutableListOf<Job>()
    repeat(1000) {
        val job = scope.launch {
            for (i in 1..1_000) {
                regularCounter++
                updateCounter()
            }
        }
        jobs.add(job)
    }

    jobs.forEach { it.join() }

    println("The number of shared counter is $sharedCounter")
    println("The number of regular counter is $regularCounter")
}
```

should result in both `sharedCounter` and `regularCounter` NOT being equal to `1000000`.

This code was based on [this](https://blog.danlew.net/2020/01/28/coroutines-and-java-synchronization-dont-mix/) and [this](https://proandroiddev.com/synchronization-and-thread-safety-techniques-in-java-and-kotlin-f63506370e6d) articles.

For some reason, `sharedCounter` always equals `1000000` and I'm not sure why.
I've tried testing larger `for` loops, but it did not "break" the synchronization either.

Comment: If you want it to go wrong, in the way that the second link does, you can write `val read = sharedCounter; delay(2); sharedCounter = read + 1`

Answer (score 0):

The synchronization lock is released at each suspend function call, but re-acquired before continuing. In your code, `delay()` and `yield()` are the suspension points. But `sharedCounter++` is all local code, so the lock is held while it performs its three steps of getting the value, incrementing it, and setting it. So, the first `delay()` releases the lock, the continuation resumes so it re-locks and performs `sharedCounter++`, and then the lock is released again at the second `delay()` call.